# Synchronizing parallel loops in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, for-loop, synchronization, multiprocessing

How would I get for loops in parallel processes to execute such that each process waits until all other loops in the other processes have finished one iteration before incrementing `i` to the next iteration? In this case, each iteration will take a different amount of time depending on the size of vector you are generating, and I want all the loops to step through the iterations synchronously.

```
    import multiprocessing
    import numpy as np;
    def calc(num):
        for i in range(0,10):
            x=np.random.rand(int(num));
            y=np.random.poisson(x)
            print("NUM: "+str(int(num))+" IT: " +str(i)+"\n")
        return 0;

    if __name__=='__main__':  
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3) 
        for output in pool.map(calc, [1,2e3,3e6]):
            print 'output:',output
```

Thanks!

EDIT: The output I'm looking for should be something like...

```
NUM: 1 IT: 0
NUM: 2000 IT: 0
NUM: 3000000 IT: 0
NUM: 1 IT: 1
NUM: 2000 IT: 1
NUM: 3000000 IT: 1
NUM: 1 IT: 2
NUM: 2000 IT: 2
NUM: 3000000 IT: 2
NUM: 1 IT: 3
NUM: 2000 IT: 3
NUM: 3000000 IT: 3
```

Comment: Seems like you want a [barrier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects) (requires Python 3.2 however).

Comment: @PeteyPii - I got Barrier to work for a for loop. How would I do it for a while loop with a variable number of iterations? If one loop ends earlier than another loop then the entire program deadlocks because the barriers in the other processes are waiting for a process that exited the loop to hit the barrier.wait().

Comment: If the separate threads have distinct iteration counts then you can simply add another loop after the first while loop that only calls barrier.wait() n times where n is the max iteration count minus the particular thread's iteration count.

Comment: They are variable iteration counts. I solved the issue by using a shared memory flag. Thanks for your help!